# "403 Forbidden" for TIdTCPClient::Connect() + TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy

Tags: c++, proxy, indy, c++builder-xe2

С++, Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2

I need connect to a ::6100 with TIdTCPClient through http-proxy. So I wrote this code:

```
    m_pClient = new TIdTCPClient( NULL );

    m_pClient->Host = m_sServerAddress.c_str();
    m_pClient->Port = StrToInt( m_sServerPort.c_str() );
    m_pClient->ConnectTimeout = 5000;
    m_pClient->ReadTimeout = 5000;

    if ( m_bUseProxy == true )
    {
        m_pIdIOHandlerStack = new TIdIOHandlerStack( NULL );

        m_pIdIOHandlerStack->TransparentProxy = new TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy( m_pIdIOHandlerStack );
        m_pIdIOHandlerStack->TransparentProxy->Host = m_sProxyHost;
        m_pIdIOHandlerStack->TransparentProxy->Port = m_iProxyPort;
        m_pIdIOHandlerStack->TransparentProxy->Enabled = True;

        m_pClient->IOHandler = m_pIdIOHandlerStack;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pClient->IOHandler = NULL;
    }

    <other code>

    m_pClient->Connect();
```

I got an exeption "403 forbidden" on "Connect"
proxy: 5.196.0.118::3128
I can connect to this server without proxy or ping it.
I used this proxy server successfully with my browser, but I can't use it for my code.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You likely need to assign a proxy username/password to `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy`. If that still does not work, then use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to compare the browser's proxy request to `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy`'s request to find out what is different between them.

Comment: It looks like username and password were necessary for anonymous proxies too. It works now, thank you! I didn't believe that it can help ))